# angularJS bindings getting destroyed on traversing the flipbook(turn.js)

Tags: angularjs

angularjs + turn.js

Please refer the plunkr to see the problem..
http://plnkr.co/edit/tpzVrq0ISarXVnttK3oH?p=preview

Problem:
logging the ng-click function shows that the ng-click function is not even been called...which shows that somehow the angular bindings are getting destroyed...or the current scope is getting changed??

Condition for which this problem occurs:

1. Total number of pages>6. &&
2. Traversed to the page>6.

Knowing what actually is happening behind the scenes while calling

> .turn('page', #)

might solve the problem, or is there a way to recreate or recompile the ng-directives...

Please help..

Comment: You are missing jQuery, it seems to be a dependency since the selectors of turn.js seem to need them (and angular jqlite doesn't have all the selectors that jQuery has), plus the script.js is in wrong order, and has no angular code in it... maybe the plnkr code you showed is wrong?

Comment: I wonder what link you saw, because jQuery is already added there before angular.min.js, and there is no such file with the name 'script.js'. Please recheck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my take (with a few cleanups on your code): http://plnkr.co/edit/W1SZRRdr1V5UVEMA3vQe?p=preview

the problem actually lies on the way `turn.js` works. it removes and re-adds the pages to the DOM, making the Angular bindings (in this case `ng-click`) go away. If you start clicking from page 3, page 6 then page 7, they stop working. If you start by page 7, then when you come back to page containing the links stops working. So you can http://plnkr.co/edit/TIwNzaOw1nde8ZAb7WQj?p=preview

Create a jQuery delegate on your links (instead of using `ng-click`):

```js
var test=angular.module('test', [])

test.directive('flipbook', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    compile: function(element, attrs){
      element.turn({
        width: '300px',
        height: '300px',
        pages: 8,
      }).turn('peel','br');

      element.addClass('flipbook');

      return function(scope, el) {
        el.on('click', '[data-page]', function(e){
          el.turn('page', $(e.target).data('page'));
        });
      };
    },
    templateUrl: "flipbook.html"
  }
});
```

this always happen when you are mixing jQuery and Angular, that in this case is impossible to not mix them two. Another way is to compose using different directives for pages, page links, etc, that they get recompiled when they need (sub directives). But the problem with bound events will remain an issue

Comment: np, click the "Accept answer" button :)