# angularJS bindings getting destroyed for image using turn.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, turnjs

I'm trying to make an image-book using turn.js and angular.js
i want to set height & width of image dynamically according to device(mobile / PC) height & width..

Somehow i am able get height & width of the device But i cannot set using angular bind i.e.{{height}}.

Problem Occured when we traverse to page 6...
To Understand clearly i have set same image...

On page 6 the image doesn't set height/width according to angular bind..i.e.{{height}}

My controller Looks like..

```
test.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.height=210; // can change dynamically
  $scope.width=150;// can change dynamically
});
```

Image tag looks like..

```
<img height="{{height}}" width="{{width}}" src="image.jpg">
```

i have set height & width in controller which can change according to device 
[here is plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X09R7zoXF5GKWLbArrRf?p=preview)

Comment: Check this thread out -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599891/angularjs-bindings-getting-destroyed-on-traversing-the-flipbookturn-js